# I'm updating shopware version from v6.3.5.4 to v6.4.13.0 and I get 'Slim Aplication Error'

Tags: shopware, shopware6, shopware6-api, shopware6-app

[image: 1]

after I change the code from the new version on this file /var/www/html/vendor/shopware/recovery/Update/src/DependencyInjection/Container.php,
this error appear to me.
[image: 2]

Can someone help me?!

Comment: Please explain in more detail how you attempted to update and what you did to so.

Comment: Please add actual code instead of screenshots, if possible!

Comment: What code? There is no code, I was updating in the backend clicking on a button now to the newest version and I get almost the same error:
Slim Application Error
The application could not run because of the following error:

Details
Type: TypeError
Message: trim() expects parameter 1 to be string, bool given
File: shop/vendor/shopware/recovery/Update/src/DependencyInjection/Container.php
Line: 41